# PHP curl execution permissions and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I'm trying to execute php script on my server with a curl command. The script is located in a folder that is restricted with an .htaccess file to a handful of IPs, including my servers, for security reasons.

I can include this file with php includes without a problem but I can seem to execute it with the following curl command (this works when the folder is not restricted):

```
<?php 
// Execute the file server side. 
$fileurl = ("https://example.com/restrictedfolder/xyz12345.php");
exec("nohup curl ".$fileurl." > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
?>
```

I was under the impression that htaccess didnt restrict php from accessing files (as demonstrated by the includes) but this doesnt seem to be the case with CURL.

Is there any way to get round this to execute the file on the server side but keep it restricted from the public?

Comment: Have you got `127.0.0.1` in your handful of IPs?

Comment: no I haven't, what does that do?

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood - are you executing the curl command on the same machine as the remote PHP script? 127.0.0.1 is (generally) the IP that you'll be coming from if accessing a file on the same system.

Comment: I'm executing the curl command on my local machine to run a script on a server however i want to restrict the folder that the script lives in from anyone directly accessing the files from their local machines, I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was under the impression that htaccess didnt restrict php from
>   accessing files (as demonstrated by the includes) but this doesnt seem
>   to be the case with CURL.

Your script doesn't access files. It loads a URL through Apache, just like a regular browser.

You can do two things to diagnose:

1. Capture and display Curl error messages (rather than sending them to `/dev/null`)
2. See Apache error logs (where restricted IPs get logged as *AH01630: client denied by server configuration*)

Most likely, you haven't allowed your own local IP address.